# Contract.on event listener not working (using Ethers.js + Next.js), how come?

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, events, event-handling, nextjs

got a simple question here for all you ethers.js hackers. Simple code, transactions go through, but why doesn't the `contract.on` function work?

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTRACT_ADDRESS_SEPOLIA,
      ABI,
      signer
    );
  
    // Attach the event listener
    contract.on("MessageChanged", (newPrice, messenger) => {
      console.log(newPrice, messenger);
    });
  
    // Now send the transaction
    await contract.setMessage(message, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther(price) });
  };
```

The transaction goes through, but the event listener does not fire. Why?